# Jmeter: Runtime Error on Welcome page after Login Page

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, blazemeter

I have two request one is Login which ask for userid,pass,financial year and branch name. second request is welcome page which show the admin detail like userid,LoginBranch,branch Code, Login status-admin.

here for 1st request i used csv file which pass userid,password,branch name, financial year. In Send Parameter request there are only these three value present .I replaced them by ${user},${pass},${year},${branchname}.This Login request running successfully.
 next request is welCome (Get Method)
This page show the details like userid,LoginBranch,branch Code, Login status-admin.There is no send request parameter. these value come from login request .
but in login request there is no "branch code" value . this branch code value coming from server database. How to extract this branch code and place it to welcome page ?

Comment: Remove the tag loadrunner as this question is for Jmeter, please.

Comment: Some LoadRunner expert can give the answer of Jmeter question's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) to extract branch code value from the database.

1. Download [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database and drop it to JMeter's /lib folder.
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) element to your test plan. Put your database URL, driver class name and credentials there. Also specify an arbitrary "Variable Name"
4. Add JDBC PreProcessor as a child of "Welcome" request
5. Configure it as follows:

   - Specify the same "Variable Name" as in step 3.
   - In "SQL Query" put the query which will return desired branch code
   - In "Variable Names" put something meaningful, like `branch_code`
6. Use `${branch_code_1}` in your Welcome GET request

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) guilde for detailed instructions on how to set up JMeter for being able to talk to databases.